# Django import problem, cant import myapp but i have installed it in setings

Tags: javascript, python, django

I'm working on a Django project and encountering an ImportError when trying to import a function from my app into the urls.py file. Despite the function being defined and the app added to INSTALLED_APPS, Django cannot seem to locate the function.
Project Structure:
myproject/
manage.py
dictionarapicol/
**init**.py
settings.py
urls.py
asgi.py
wsgi.py
statics/
find.js

```
myapp/
    migrations/
        __init__.py
    templates/
       base.htm
       index.html

    __init__.py
    text_processing.py
    admin.py
    apps.py
    models.py
    tests.py
    views.py
    urls.py
```

myapp/urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from myapp import views
from .text_processing import process_text

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='index'),
    path('contact/', views.contact, name='contact'),
    path('stiri_apicole/', views.login, name='stiri_apicole'),
    path('text_processing/', process_text, name='text_processing'),
]
```

text_processing.py

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
import json
from nltk.stem.snowball import SnowballStemmer
import stanza
import spacy_stanza
from rowordnet import RoWordNet

# Load dictionary data
with open('static\dictionary.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    dictionary_data = json.load(file)

# Initialize NLTK, spaCy, Stanza, andin stall RoWordNet
stemmer = SnowballStemmer("romanian")
nlp = spacy_stanza.load_pipeline('ro')
import rowordnet as rwn
wn = RoWordNet()

def process_text(request):
    text = request.GET.get('text', '')
    stemmed_text = stemmer.stem(text)
    doc = nlp(text)
    lemmatized_text = ' '.join([token.lemma_ for token in doc])
    synset_ids = wn.synsets(literal=text)
    synsets = [wn.synset(synset_id).definition for synset_id in synset_ids]

    return JsonResponse({
        'stemmed_text': stemmed_text,
        'lemmatized_text': lemmatized_text,
        'RoWordNet_synsets': synsets
    })
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')

def contact(request):
    return render(request, 'contact.html')

def login(request):
'stiri_apicole.html')

# views.py
from .text_processing import process_text
```

find.js

```
ocument.getElementById('searchInput').addEventListener('input', function (e) {
    const searchTerm = e.target.value;

    // Send the search term to Django backend for processing
    fetch(`text_processing.py/?text=${encodeURIComponent(searchTerm)}`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            // Use processed text (stemmed, lemmatized, etc.) from backend for Fuse.js search
            // Assuming the backend sends back a similar JSON structure
            const processedText = data.lemmatized_text; // Choose between stemmed_text or lemmatized_text
            const results = fuse.search(processedText);
            displayResults(results.map(result => result.item));
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error("Error processing text:", error);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCEOL.png)

I've verified that **init**.py exists in each directory, so Python should recognize them as packages.
I've tried importing process_text directly in views.py and then referencing it in urls.py, but the error persists.
The app is included in INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py.

Comment: Does `views.contact` and `views.login` work as expected?

Comment: Obligatory nitpicking, define your `login` view properly.

Comment: Since you have imported `process_text` in `views.py`, use it directly from `views` in `urls.py`.

Comment: Does views.contact and views.login work as expected? yes they work, and home as well.

Comment: as i said in the other coment on debugging it apear that the whole my app is not imported

Comment: now i got this error as well: moduleNotFoundError: No module named 'views'

Comment: If they do work as expected, what convinced you that there is an `ImportError`? Do you get any errors from running `python manage.py runserver` or is it only from visual studio’s linter that you are seeing errors? You have to let python run your code first to be sure that there are actually errors.

Comment: i have run the server i get error in the browser console and now after a i''ve made the change you sugestet i get this error prom the server :ile "C:\Users\User\dictionarapicol\myapp\urls.py", line 3, in <module>
    from views import process_text
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'views'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make the following changes to your code
in the `views.py`

```py
from django.shortcuts import render

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')

def contact(request):
    return render(request, 'contact.html')

def login(request):
    return render(request, 'stiri_apicole.html')

# Notice that this line has been removed?
```

And in the `urls.py`

```py
from django.urls import path
from myapp import views, text_processing

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='index'),
    path('contact/', views.contact, name='contact'),
    path('stiri_apicole/', views.login, name='stiri_apicole'),
    path('text_processing/', text_processing.process_text, name='text_processing'),
]
```

Comment: now i get no errors on the server  side but when i try to use the search bar i get this errors in the browser :ailed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
find.js:28 
        
        
       GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/text_processing.py/?text=f 404 (Not Found)
(anonymous) @ find.js:28
find.js:38 Error processing text: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSOn

Comment: In `fetch(`text_processing.py/?text=${encodeURIComponent(searchTerm)}`)`, the `fetch()` is hitting an invalid url. A url that does not exist. The url `text_processing.py/` does not exist. Your urls that exist are `contact/`, `stiri_apicole/`, `text_processing/` and the base url. Hence the 404 error.

Answer (score -1):

Try the following which might help

1. Import using project directory name as package for import. Reduces bug and easier to migrate in future

Example:

```
from myapp.text_processing import process_text
```

2. Always import packages at top, it is a standard practice

Comment: i have tried that, and now i've runed a debbug on urls.py and it does not import the whole myapp': No module named 'myapp'

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn’t answer the question.